# How can I save nested arrays of entities in TypeORM?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I'm using postgresql with typeORM in an express app, I have a `Game` entity that has many `Question` entities that have many `Answer` entities, now I'm trying to build an endpoint that will add a new Game to the database from a JSON. However I don't know how to do this and the approach I'm trying is giving me different errors.

These are the entities:

**Game.entity.ts**

```js
@Entity()
export class Game {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Column({})
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => User, (user) => user.id)
  user: User;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @OneToMany(() => Question, (question) => question.game, {
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
  })
  questions: Question[];
}
```

**Question.entity.ts**

```js
@Entity()
export class Game {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Column({})
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => User, (user) => user.id)
  user: User;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @OneToMany(() => Question, (question) => question.game, {
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
  })
  questions: Question[];
}
```

**Answer.entity.ts**

```js
@Entity()
export class Answer {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  index: number;

  @Column()
  answer!: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Question, (question) => question.answers, {
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
  })
  question: Question;
}
```

And this is the functions I wrote to save the Game to the DB, I'm calling `createGame` which calls the `addQuestion` who calls the `addAnswer` function :

```js
export const typeORMGameDao: GameDao<Game, Question, Answer> = {
  addAnswer: async (
    answer: AnswerModel,
    question: Question
  ): Promise<Answer> => {
    console.log("creating new answer", answer.answer);
    const newAnswer = new Answer();
    newAnswer.answer = answer.answer;
    newAnswer.question = question;

    try {
      return await AppDataSource.getRepository(Answer).save(newAnswer);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error adding answer", error);
      return;
    }
  },
  addQuestion: async (
    question: QuestionModel,
    game: Game
  ): Promise<Question> => {
    console.log("creating new question", question.question);
    const newQuestion = new Question();
    newQuestion.question = question.question;
    newQuestion.score = question.score;
    newQuestion.correct_answer = question.correct_answer;
    newQuestion.game = game;
    newQuestion.answers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
      const answer = await typeORMGameDao.addAnswer(
        question.answers[i],
        newQuestion
      );
      if (answer) newQuestion.answers.push(answer);
    }
    try {
      return await AppDataSource.getRepository(Question).save(newQuestion);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error adding question", error);
      return;
    }
  },
  createGame: async (game: GameModel, user: User): Promise<Game> => {
    console.log("creating new game", game.name);
    const newGame = new Game();
    newGame.user = user;
    newGame.name = game.name;
    for (let i = 0; i < game.questions.length; i++) {
      const question = await typeORMGameDao.addQuestion(
        game.questions[i],
        newGame
      );
      if (question) newGame.questions.push(question);
    }

    try {
      return await AppDataSource.getRepository(Game).save(newGame);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error creating game", error);
      return;
    }
  },
};
```